# Display data from database depending on the how many I have entered

Tags: php, mysql

In my database and more specific in the table named **portfolio** a user with a speficic username can store more than one data. The columns of the database are **id**,**username**,**portfolio** and **portfolio_description**

[image]

and I want to echo in my web page all the data for this username for example username=nbourlai. Until now I can echo only the first row for each username what is the loop that i can use in order to echo as many time is the id number.
Below is the current result and i want to create Portfolio and Portfolio description to be displayed with the appropriate values as many time as  the highest id number is for the specific user.

[image]

Here is my code...

```
$portfolio = queryMysql("SELECT portfolio,portfolio_description FROM portfolio WHERE username='nbourlai'");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($portfolio);
echo "<h2>Portfolio</h2>";
echo "Portfolio: ";
echo stripslashes($row[0]) . "<br/>Portfolio Description: ";
echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for while loop like this?

```
$portfolio = queryMysql("SELECT portfolio,portfolio_description FROM portfolio WHERE username='nbourlai'");
echo "<h2>Portfolio</h2>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($portfolio)){
    echo "Portfolio: ";
    echo stripslashes($row[0]) . "<br/>Portfolio Description: ";
    echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
}
```

or, like this?

```
$portfolio = queryMysql("SELECT username,portfolio,portfolio_description FROM portfolio ORDER BY username");
$username = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($portfolio)){
    if($username != $row[0]){
        echo "<h1>".$row[0]."</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Portfolio</h2>";
        echo "Portfolio: ";
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br/>Portfolio Description: ";
        echo stripslashes($row[2]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
    }else{
        echo "Portfolio: ";
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br/>Portfolio Description: ";
        echo stripslashes($row[2]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";         
    }
    $username = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: i believe that I want a while loop that "runs" and check if we have more than one id for the user and every time that it finds one more id it executes those echos

Comment: @niklakis You mean you want to `echo` only when there are more than one portfolios for the user?

Comment: yes exactly not only more than one but also one is a possibility. I want to echo as many time as i have in the id for the specific user . For example if i have id=3 I want to echo 3 times that data

Comment: @niklakis It is my first answer, isn't it?